# Format decimal output from sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to split up the result of the following sql query in html that way to style the decimals?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vendordb_3_postmeta WHERE meta_id = 25";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['meta_value']."<br />";
}
?>
```

The output is a product-price like 999.99 The aim is to style the decimals superscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to format a part of the string, you'll need to split it up into pieces that can be formatted separately.

If you want a result like

> 999<sup>99</sup>

you can split it up using `explode()`. This will split your `999.99` into an array with two elements, `999` and `99` (what's before and what's after the separator). You can then format it like below

```
$values = explode(".", $row['meta_value']);
echo $values[0]."<sup>".$values[1]."</sup><br />";
```

## References

- http://www.php.net/explode